# Unable to run garden install xpopup on windows

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, designer, kivy-language

I'm using python 3.7 and I'm trying to run kivy designer but when I try to run this command

```
garden install xpopup
```

I received this error:

```
(null): can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I already tried upgrading of previous modules, all Requirements are already satisfied. What to do now?

Comment: As a guess, you've probably installed into `C:\Program Files\some-directory` and the installer is choking on the space in the directory name (and because you're using Windows). Reinstall to a path without spaces and it will probably work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, problem resolved :)